# How to not write a line if it is of differing length in Python

Tags: python, file, csv, io

I'm trying to combine CSV files and there is some evidence of corruption that I would like to remove. some of the lines are not the same length as the others and if that is the case I do not want to write them to the master file. This is the code I am using to accomplish that

```
for line in rest:
     if len(line.split(",")) == good_line_length or line == "\n":
         processed_file_write.write(line)
     else:
          pass
```

Where good line length is the `len(csv_header.split(","))`

I am trying this and it spits out a newline instead of passing over the line and not writing anything. If i replace the `pass` with `processed_file_write.write("DUMMY")` then it writes "DUMMY" instead of the newline. I don't know how to make python just skip writing the line.

Comment: what happens if you print the length of the line? maybe it doesn't match the length of the header

Comment: Why do you include `or line == "\n"`?  A simple test of `if len(line.split(",")) == good_line_length:` rules out all bad lines.  (This presumes of course that you don't have quoted fields.  If you do, use the `csv` module.)

Comment: @user2314737 Printing the length of the line gives me varying results from 2 to 9

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I tried not including the newline check and get the same result. I added the newline check because I thought it was to do with a newline

Comment: If you want us to debug this, you need to give us a [mcve],  (including a small sample input file) that reproduces this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you used Python's CSV library to help with this. It will read each line and automatically do the split for you. You can then compare the number of items in a row with the number of items in your header as follows:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv', newline='') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    header = next(csv_input)
    csv_output.writerow(header)

    for row in csv_input:
        if len(row) == len(header):
            csv_output.writerow(row)
```

This shows how it would work for a single file. The `csv.writer()` will automatically put the comma delimiters back in when writing each row.